# How do I set a completion activity for a CountDown timer in Android?

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I am trying to create a countdown timer that counts down for 60 seconds (optionally skippable by the user).  That part of the code works.  How do I make it so an action is taken upon the completion of the countdown timer (the same action as the button does, ending the activity).

```
public void startCountdown(int total, final int increase) {
    final TimerClassExtended timer = new TimerClassExtended(total,1000);

    timer.start();


    Button skip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.skip);
    skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            timer.cancel();
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }

    });

}
```

Figured it out, had to modify the following line.  But I can't answer myself for 8 hours...

For future reference, TimerClassExtended is just a class I made that extends CountDownTimer so I could add extra methods that I needed.

```
final TimerClassExtended timer = new TimerClassExtended(total,1000) {
        public void onFinish() {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    };
```

Comment: What is TimerClassExtended? That is not part of the Android or Java SDK, therefore we have no knowledge of the capabilities of this class, therefore no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Good point.  It was just a class i created that extended CountDownTimer to create some extra methods in.  I figured it out though, thanks.  Can't add my own answer for 7 more hours though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had a custom class I added the following:

```
final TimerClassExtended timer = new TimerClassExtended(total,1000) {
    public void onFinish() {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge of the class you are using, but you might consider using a `TimerTask` and scheduling it for 60000ms.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule( task, 60000 );
```

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that but CountDownTimer was better for displaying on the screen the countdown.  I did figure it out though, thanks.